# Draw 32x32 Tiled Images in QT

Tags: qt, dictionary, tile

I'm curious to learn how to split an image into 32x32 (or really any size) selectable tiles and display them in *Qt*? An example is the **Tiled Map Editor** (the panel in the lower right corner of the screen). I'm thinking of trying to create a 2D level editor in *Qt* for fun but I'm fairly new to *Qt* and have yet to find the answer to this specific question. Or maybe I just don't know how to phrase the question.

Comment: There is a [**embedded lighmaps demo**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-embedded-lightmaps.html) in either the *example* or *demo* directory that comes in the Qt distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your main image to a QPixmap, then for each tile that you want to create, call the QPixmap's copy function. This allows you to specify the area that you want to copy and returns you a new QPixmap with that area.

With each QPixmap tile you create using copy, use this to create a QGraphicsPixmapItem, which you then add to the QGraphicsScene.

So, you'd do something like this: -

```
// assuming your source image is in your resources qrc file
QPixmap srcImage(":/images/srcImage.png");

//in a loop for x and a 2nd loop for y

// copy a section of the source image
QPixmap tileImg = srcImage.copy(x, y, w, h);

// create the tile
QGraphicsPixmapItem* pTile = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(tileImg);

// add the pTile to the scene.
```

Using QGraphicsPixmapItem will provide you with a tiled object that can be positioned in the scene, selected and moved about.

Comment: Thanks Merlin069. I'll use this method.